# bash : how to use screen to have a term session used at home after work?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

Everything is in the title, I would like to start a session at work and be able to get it when i'm at home.

Comment: please describe in a lot more detail what you want? where do you want to have that session? at home? at work?

Comment: thought this was clear, thank for the -1 ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While at work, start a screen session:

```
$ screen
```

Do whatever work you want on the terminal session, and when you are leaving to go home, **detach** the session by pressing **CTRL-A** then **D**. Your screen session will then disappear. To re-activate it once you are home, **resume** the session with the **-r** option:

```
$ screen -r
```

All your work will appear as you enter the saved screen session.

Comment: I personally prefer always using screen -R, which connects to an existing session if one exists, otherwise it creates one.